# Drawing graph line using Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, graph, core-graphics

I am trying draw an random graph which display on imageview, I try this code

```
-(void)createGraph{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];    
        CGContextRef context    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
        int i = 0;
        while (i<=20) {
            int r = rand() % 100;

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, 320);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, linePoint.x+20+i*r, linePoint.y+320-i*r);         
            CGContextStrokePath(context);   
            i++;

            NSLog(@"random value %d",r);
        }
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
```

But its drawing a diagonal on single line.  has show in below image

I am expecting to draw a graph line! using coregraphics
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot put `CGContextAddLineToPoint` into the loop. Remove (just) the loop, and make another loop in e.g. `viewDidLoad`, at each iteration, call `-(void)createGraph` giving the last point and the next one. Now the last point you will assign to `CGContextMoveToPoint`, and the next point you will give to `CGContextAddLineToPoint`. By the way, add `CGContextBeginPath(context);` right after `CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);`

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //X_Line, Y_Line, x and y are integer variables
    X_Line = 20;
    Y_Line = 320;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        x = x + arc4random() % 100;
        y = x + arc4random() % 100;
        [self createGraph];
    }
}

-(void)createGraph
{  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgView.frame.size);
    [imgView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];    
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, X_Line, Y_Line);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x , y);         
    CGContextStrokePath(context);   
    imgView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    X_Line = x;
    Y_Line = y;
}
```

Comment: @kiran - Now try this code.... Sorry for my mistake, I had been taken your question wrong.... :-(

Comment: Thanks ... yesterday i was totally wrong ... well glad to know it helped you :-)

Comment: Yep Its on load its working When i am navigation from one view and getting back its changing its location.

Comment: yes because every time you are generating random numbers for X and Y co-ordinates.